# Extract entities (like dates or location) from a string in Swift

Tags: swift, nlp, named-entity-extraction

I want to achieve a simmilar thing to the iOS messages on WhatsApp where **Dates** are extracted from a message. I found out that this is called **entity extraction**.

My question is: Does Apple have native APIs for this?

I've found [MLKit's take](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/language/entity-extraction/ios) on this but the entity extraction by apple seems more advanced, since it can also recognize Timespans.

I've come across NLTagger but this does not seem to have support for Dates (only Names and named locations).